# webサービスのURL末尾に文字列をつけてページを生成し、入力データをサーバーに保存する方法を知りたい

Tags: php, node.js

webサービスのURL末尾に文字列をつけてページを生成し、
そこに入力されたデータをサーバーに保存したり、
編集する方法を知りたいです。

例えば下記のようなURLにアクセスすると、
https://hoge.au/
自動的に下記のようなURLが生成されてユーザーがそこに飛ばされ、
https://hoge.au/wukolxcj
そこにユーザーが入力したものを保存したいです。
また、同じURLにアクセスすると、入力の続きを行えるようにしたいです。

イメージとして下記のサービスに近いです
https://notepad.bz

これを実現するにあたり、node jsかphpでの設計方法をアドバイスいただけないでしょうか？

なお私の状況としては、phpやnode js、javascriptは一通り扱えます(webサービスも作ったことがあります)。
ですので「あのメソッドとこのメソッドを使ってああしてみたら？」という感じのアドバイスをいただきたいです。

また、どう調べたら良いのかも困っているので、
「〜で検索しろ」のようなキーワードだけでも教えていただけると助かります。

Comment: 質問の幅が広すぎる気がします。また、user27439さんが何ができて何ができないのかを記載したほうが良いかと。（普通の？webアプリケーションの作成ならば問題ないのか、そもそもnode.jsやphpの構文もわからないのか。など。。。）

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHPであれば`uniqid`関数などを用いて**何らかのユニークな値を生成**し、その値をファイル名やデータベースのキーとして用いてユーザーからの入力を保存、表示するのが一般的ではないでしょうか。

参考：
[PHPでユニークなIDを生成する：uniqid()](http://kakakakakku.hatenablog.com/entry/20081016/1224154493)

```
<?php
    // $prefix(接頭辞)なしで利用すると，13文字の文字列が生成される．
    echo uniqid();
    echo uniqid("");            // [例] 48f7146e6ea07

    // より安全な(推測されにくい)文字列を得たい場合は，
    // uniqid()で生成されたユニークIDのハッシュ値を取ればよい．
    echo md5(uniqid(rand(),1)); // [例] 846189340160532f6c51bf26ab596f55
?>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。参考になりました。